# Giving faces compliant names

Tags: faces, font-lock, variables, coding-conventions, elisp-conventions

The description of `defface` in `(info "(elisp) Defining Faces")`
says that the name of a face should ***not*** end in `-face`. But
most faces declared in `font-lock.el` do use the suffix `-face`.
How does this fit together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are exceptions. ;-)

Some may be vestiges. In the Olden Days it was common to have both a variable for the face and the face itself, and the variable, or both, had a name that ended in `-face`.

Some are not just vestiges, at least for the variables. One reason to have a variable is to be able to bind it, to temporarily change which face is used. This is not common.

In the case of font-lock faces, there is this comment (from @Stefan Monnier) in the code (`font-lock.el`), which explains things:

```lisp
;; Originally these variable values were face names such as `bold' etc.
;; Now we create our own faces, but we keep these variables for compatibility
;; and they give users another mechanism for changing face appearance.
;; We now allow a FACENAME in `font-lock-keywords' to be any expression that
;; returns a face.  So the easiest thing is to continue using these variables,
;; rather than sometimes evalling FACENAME and sometimes not.  sm.

;; Note that in new code, in the vast majority of cases there is no
;; need to create variables that specify face names.  Simply using
;; faces directly is enough.  Font-lock is not a template to be
;; followed in this area.
(defvar font-lock-comment-face      'font-lock-comment-face
  "Face name to use for comments.")
```

Comment: Maybe, it is good to know that faces are actually managed in `face-...` properties of a symbol (`face-defface-spec`, `face-override-spec`, `customized-face`, `saved-face`). That makes is possible to use one symbol for a variable and a face simultaneously. Last time I read the manual in that respect it was a bit vague. One got the wrong impression that faces are a separate primitive type.